# Can't load x509 certificate in python

Tags: python, certificate, loading, x509certificate, x509

I'm facing an issue in loading the certificate I've generated in x509.

```
    Cer = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(f.read(), default_backend())
```

The Error raised is as follow:

```
ValueError: Unable to load certificate. See https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-can-t-i-import-my-pem-file for more details.
```

I've tried all the possible solutions but still, I didn't find any solution to the error.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know you have the correct format? Does the first line say `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes. I already make sure that the format is absolutely correct...

Comment: Does the following command raise an error: `openssl x509 -in your_certificate.pem -noout -text`